# Score indicator of "accepted" posts in user profile became black text on green background

Tags: bug, status-completed, accessibility

It used to be white text on green background. I think this is a bug and leads to poor contrast.

*Newest posts* in *Profile* tab:

[image: Newest posts list]

*Answers* in *Activity* tab (same for *Questions*):

[image: Answers list]

According to https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent/, these screenshots were made with

> Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0

Comment: Also reported on MSE: [Green reputation badges on Summary page have black text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384261/241919) (already fixed, waiting for deploy)

Comment: For the curious: [this is how it looks in high contrast dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPDP3.png)

Comment: @VLAZ wow. Such contrast. Much great. 11/5 would read again

Comment: Weird. I was saying earlier that I have no problem reading the image in the question here. But in the "high contrast", supposedly easier-to-read version, I can't even tell a number is present, let alone read it.

Comment: It seems to be fixed now.